# Declaración de cursores T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Mi duda es si en la declaracion del cursor no especificamos ningun parametro de comportamiento del mismo como por ejemplo `SCROLL` o `LOCAL` o `READ_ONLY`, que valor tomará por defecto?

Es decir si yo escribo esto

```
DECLARE nombreCursor CURSOR FOR sentencia
```

¿que parámetro tomara por defecto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) hay una nota interesante:

> Note
>
> If neither GLOBAL or LOCAL is specified, the default is controlled by
>   the setting of the default to local cursor database option.

El default contempla dos valores `LOCAL` y `GLOBAL`. Esto se configura a nivel `database` de la siguiente forma (usamos de ejemplo la `Tempdb`):

```
ALTER DATABASE TEMPDB SET CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL;
ALTER DATABASE TEMPDB SET CURSOR_DEFAULT GLOBAL;
```

Para saber cual es el default o para ser más correctos, cual es la configuración default activa, una forma es hacer lo siguiente:

```
-- 1 si es LOCAL, 0 si es Global
select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('TEMPDB', 'IsLocalCursorsDefault')
```

Otra forma es crear un cursor `dummy` y ver las propiedades del mismo

```
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR  FOR SELECT 1 AS 'ID' 
SELECT properties FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@spid);
DEALLOCATE cursor_name;
```

La Salida:

```
properties
---------------------------------------
TSQL | Snapshot | Read Only | Local (0)
```

En este ejemplo, podemos confirmar que el modo `default` configurado es `Local`

Comment: Entonces, si lo he entendido bien, si en la declaración del cursor no se especifica nada, puede que tome por defecto LOCAL o GLOBAL no?. He probado a ejecutar la sentencia que mencionaste antes `select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('TEMPDB', 'IsLocalCursorsDefault')` y me devuelve un 0. No devuelve ni 1 ni null, porque?

Comment: @SergioAG, es cierto, no retorna NULL, retorna 0 en caso de ser GLOBAL, acabo de verificarlo en un 2016, ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!